# Re generate elf symbol table

Tags: elf

I have an elf binary (x86/32 bits) which symbol table has been stripped. Is there a way to regenerate this table, with random names. And is there a way for me than to remplace the random names by names i know ?

Comment: You should use correct grammar & spelling so everyone can read-properly.